# javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Maximum Element Depth limit (1000) Exceeded

Tags: java, xml, parsing, exception

does anyone know how I can configure max element depth for ReaderConfig.class, by default it uses this value https://github.com/FasterXML/woodstox/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ctc/wstx/api/ReaderConfig.java#L44, but I couldn't change it anyway.

Because I have exception **javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Maximum Element Depth limit (1000)** Exceeded when I try to parse some big XML document.

**UPDATE:**
I've investigated it deeper, and what I saw

```
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("...../some.xml"));
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(input);

    XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
    xstream.fromXML(inputStreamReader);
```

in StaxDriver.java we have field XMLInputFactory inputFactory; that initialized StaxDriver.java#150 via XMLInputFactory.newInstance() and I can't pass any parameters for XMLInputFactory.

**NOTE:**
this exception hapends when we use com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.

I fixed this via property javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl

but for WstxInputFactory I don't see any solutions.

Comment: I I'd like to config it via a property or some more proper way.

Comment: Are you sure document legitimately has such a deep nesting? Setting can of course be changed but it seems like bit of an extreme case... there is some additional resource usage for each nesting level, for example, which could become problematic at tens or hundreds of thousands.

Comment: It's ok, maybe looks like strange but we actually have such a deep nesting. Live is a pain.

Comment: Ok. Just thought I'll mention it, sometimes devs end up solving a symptom initially, then find there's another root cause. But I hope nesting is still finite. Either way, setting can definitely be changed, to say `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, to effectively disable it.

Comment: also, fwtw, these limits were added as protection for Denial-of-Service attacks: this particular setting is less likely to be used, but some others (like nesting levels of entities) have been reported as actual existing attacks. This just as a background. Maybe default setting should be relaxed... I wonder what'd be highest reported actual nesting: setting it to, say, 10,000 would probably not make big difference to DoS protection, for example.

Comment: Then the library you are using is somewhat broken -- use of System properties is an anti-pattern for Java systems because its settings are global and can cause side-effects when multiple libraries or frameworks try to use same library (like woodstox) but with different settings.
So `StaxDriver` needs to either (a) take an `XMLInputFactory`, (b) expose such factory for configuration or (c) have a method that takes key+value and configure factory.
This is how Stax factories are configured.

Answer (score 1):

Call this method for your instance of `ReaderConfig`:

```
public void setMaxElementDepth(int value) {
    mMaxElementDepth = value;
}
```

Comment: Yep, I did it in debug mode, but I'd like to config it via a property or some more proper way.

Comment: So configure it by reading a property and calling that method in your code.

Comment: FWIW, there doesn't appear to be any std support for configuring STAX parsers from config files.

Comment: Stax API does not support that, no. But the official mechanism of calling `setProperty()` on `XMLInputFactory` is the way to do it in somewhat portable way (alas there is no standard mechanism for detecting which properties impls support).

Answer (score 0):

No, pay no attention to `ReaderConfig` (or `WriterConfig`).
That is internal class: all configuration should go through standard `setProperty()` method in `XMLInputFactory` and `XMLOutputFactory`.

Keys to use are defined in another classes; standard Stax ones within factory class; Stax2 extensions in their counterparts (I think `XMLInputFactory2`/`XMLOutputFactory2`, or, possibly, `XMLStreamReader2` / `XMLStreamWriter2`); and Woodstox' own properties in `WstxInputProperties` and `WstxOutputProperties`.

Comment: I used **-Dcom.ctc.wstx.maxEntityDepth**  but it didn't work.

Comment: @AlexPriadko that would set a "system property" and Stax does not use those for configuration (although allows it for wiring input/output factory). You need to explicitly set the values programmatically via `XMLInputFactory` / `XMLOutputFactory` instance.

Comment: hi @staxman, I've added some update for the topic, could you please take a look?